# API to filter new user registration $POST data?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Is there an `add_filter` where you can see/modify all the `$_POST` data submitted for a new user registration before the user is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well once I looked into it, it is quite simple. `$_POST` is global variable and contains all the POSTed data that was sent from the form.

For example, to email yourself all the posted data submitted in the form, you you could use something like this:

```
    function email_me_post_data() {
        global $_POST;
        $msg = print_r($_POST, true);
        mail('me@myemail.com', 'Example POST data', $msg);
    }
    add_action( 'user_register', 'email_me_post_data' );
```

Note that user_register action occurs AFTER the new user is created. Not sure you can get to the post data before user is created, although you could still modify data and re-save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`register_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post) hook. 
Here is the list of hooks and filters that fire during user reg (in order that they are fired):

1. [`register_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post) - used to handle post data from a user registration before the `registration_errors` filter is called or errors are returned
2. [`registration_errors`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) -  filters the errors encountered when a new user is being registered.
3. [`user_register`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) - allows you to access data for a new user immediately after they are added to the database

Comment: register_post only passes login and email but not the rest of the data that was POSTed.

Comment: What else do you want to check? A custom field?